# Getting successive element that is repeated in a list n times prologue

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to make function that returns element witch is repeated n times in a list. Something like this:

```
repeat([a,a,c,a,b,b,b,b,a,g],4,E).
```

And result of this should be `E = b`. What is the easiest way of doing so? Also those 4 elements have to be successive.

The code to get all elements occurrences count:

```
precondition(Clause):-
    Clause =.. [_|ARGS],
    ( maplist(var,ARGS) -> true; Clause ).

count( [], [] ).

count( [X], [(X,1)] ) :- !.

count( [H|Q], [(H,1),(HR,NR)|QR] ) :-
    count( Q, [(HR,NR)|QR] ),
    H \= HR,
    !.

count( [H|Q], [(H,NR)|QR] ) :-
    precondition( succ(N,NR) ),
    count( Q, [(H,N)|QR] ),
    succ(N,NR).
```

Comment: I am trying to do it so that it would return if it its exactly 4 time. I managed to get something like this 
`R =[ (a, 2), (c, 1), (a, 1), (b, 4), (a, 1), (g, 1)].`
Just don't know how to check if the number next to letter is equal to 4 or not.

Comment: Can you please paste the code that you did? let me suggest how to check whether it is equal to 4

Comment: Did that hope it helps

Comment: You add another rule 
repeat(L,N,E):-
    count(L,X),
    member((E, N), X).

Comment: @Karpak Thanks that was what I was also looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a list like you do, you can just use `member/2`:

```
?- R = [(a, 2), (c, 1), (a, 1), (b, 4), (a, 1), (g, 1)], 
   member((Element, 4), R).
R = [(a, 2),  (c, 1),  (a, 1),  (b, 4),  (a, 1),  (g, 1)],
Element = b ;
false.
```

It would be a bit more Prolog-like if you made a list like `[a-2, c-1, a-1, ...]`, then used `member(Element-4, R)` instead. A term like `(a, b, ...)` is **not** a tuple like in other languages, and `a-b` is commonly used as a pair.

And here is how I would do it, if I would use the libraries available with SWI-Prolog:

```
L = [a,a,c,a,b,b,b,b,a,g], N = 4,
    pairs_keys_values(Ps, L, L),
    group_pairs_by_key(Ps, G),
    include([X-Xs]>>length(Xs, N), G, R),
    member(Element-_, R).
% some results you don't need
Element = b.
```

The line with `include` is not strictly necessary, but it avoids unnecessary choice points.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a few more test should be done but here is my solution (comparison operators are for integers):

```
repeat([L], 0, X) :- L \= X.
repeat([L], 1, X) :- L == X.
repeat([X|T], C, X) :- C1 is C - 1, repeat(T, C1, X).
repeat([_|T], C, X) :- repeat(T, C, X).
```

**EDIT** I noticed that the solution provided for your example will also return `E=a` but it shouldn't. So here is the new approach: generate all sublists from the given, check if generated lists contain the same element and then check if the length of those lists is the second argument `C`

```
sublist([],[]).
sublist([H|T], [H|Q]) :- sublist(T,Q).
sublist([_|T], Q) :- sublist(T,Q).

sameelements([X], X).
sameelements([X|T], X) :- sameelements(T, X).

len([], 0).
len([_|T], C) :- len(T, C1), C is C1 + 1.

repeat(L, C, X) :- sublist(L, SL), len(SL, C), sameelements(SL, X).
```